# Elements in hamburger menu on amazon.ca are sometimes not located via xpath and causes inconsistencies

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber

I'm trying to create a selenium/cucumber project that does the following:

1. Go to `amazon.ca`
2. Click on the hamburger menu (top left corner)
3. Select Kindle under Digital Content and Devices
4. Click Kindle under Kindle E-Reader
5. Click Buy Now
6. Verify User is asked for email or mobile number

There are 2 issues I'm running into:

The amazon homepage is launching without a nav bar and hamburger menu
The Kindle elements in the hamburger menu sometimes aren't located properly
Here is the project on GitHub: https://github.com/mahmood-alsaftawi/AmazonSelenium

I believe the second issue may be caused by something dynamically changing in the xpath. I've tried selecting the element by xpath, CSS selector, absolute path, text, etc. None seem to work consistently. At one point I got it working a few times in a row but eventually, it will always fail.

Here's the snippet of code for that issue:

```
@Then("click on Kindle under Kindle E-Readers")
public void clickOnKindleUnderKindleEReaders() {
    boolean kindleExists = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/ul[5]/li[3]/a")).size() > 0;
    if (!kindleExists){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div[2]/div/ul[4]/li[3]/a")).click();
    }
    else {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/ul[5]/li[3]/a")).click();
    }
    logger.info("Click on Kindle Options under Kindle E-Readers");
    logger.info("Wait for Kindle Page to render");
}
```

I'm pretty sure the if statement isn't the best way to go about this. The reason I was trying it was that I was getting 2 different xpaths when I inspected that element.

Answer (score 0):

As I often say, avoid using long Xpath expression every time. If you have an expression like 'div/span/div' or 'div[1]/span[3]/../div[4]' you are using a bad approach.

Always prefer finding an element:

- `By class: //div[@class="ClassValue"]`
- `By ID: //span[@id="TheID"]`
- `By test: //*[contains(text(),'PartiralTextToFind')]`

Follow my advice and you will get a more readable code and also more stable code for your problem.